# signature of quadratic form and block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, block-matrices

Suppose, there is a quadratic form with matrix $A = A^T$ and signature $(p,q)$. How can I find the signature of quadratic form with matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & A \\
A & A \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
?

I've tried to do block multiplication but I didn't get any useful results.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let $A$ be $n \times n$. Is your quadratic form definite, i.e., when you say signature $(p,q)$, do we have $p+q=n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $B^tAB=D$, where $B$ is invertible and $D$ is diagonal, then $$\begin{pmatrix} B^t & -B^t \\ O & B^t \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A & A \\ A & A \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} B & O \\ -B & B \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} O & O \\ B^tA & B^tA \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} B & O \\ -B & B \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} O & O \\ O & D \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: ...which means the signature is $(p,q,0,0,... 0)$ with n zeros.